# 24 hour time format starting from 0 for fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How to set first hour to 0 for fullCalendar on a week view? I use fullcalendar react component.

```
eventTimeFormat={{
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    meridiem: false,
    hour12: false
}}
```

This gives me an event time that looks like that: `24:30-02:30` but I want it to be `00:30-02:30`. Maybe I can directly set value of this header? Or fullcalendar support it natively through some settings?

Answer (score 0):

As an option I set locale to ru. It solves problem for me.

```
import ruLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/ru';

<FullCalendar
    locale={ruLocale}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @fullcalendar/moment plugin, and set
`eventTimeFormat: 'HH:mm'`,